# Где разместить completion , чтобы функция корректно держала escaping виде массива всех Product из Firestore

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firestore

```
static func creatUserTimeLineProducts(completion: @escaping ([Product]) -> ()) {
        Firestore.firestore()
        //        получаем список Магазинов
            .collection("stores")
            .getDocuments { stores, error in
                print("Магазинов: \(stores!.count)")
                //                проходим по всем Магазинам
                for store in stores!.documents {
                    let storeRef = store.reference
                    //                    заходим в Продукты
                    storeRef.collection("products")
                        .getDocuments { products, error in
                            print("Продуктов: \(products!.count)")
                            //                            получаем все Продукты
                            let prods = products?.documents.compactMap({ Product(productDict: $0.data() )})
                            for prod in prods! {
                                FBDataBase.allProdArray.append(prod)
                            }
                            completion(FBDataBase.allProdArray)

                        }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Completion нужно указывать в конце, после всех обработок. В вашем случае - перед закрывающей скобкой функции.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev , добрый день! Спасибо за ответ. Так тестировал тоже уже, но не получилось почему-то. Возможно, это связано с контекстом, в котором я вызываю данную функцию!? Вот ссылка на полный текст: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378296/timelinecollectionviewcontroller-allprod-count-всегда-равен-нулю-Из-за-асинхрон

Answer (score 0):

Поднял completion на уровень выше - в последний блок for in. Скорее всего, такой вариант связан со сложной функцией, которая вызывает данные из FireStore, Ultimгде уже все асинхронно.

Comment: Если поместить completion в цикл, то completion будет вызываться при каждом проходе цикла. Как вариант, можно сделать счетчик прохода for in и вызвать completion при достижении его последнего значения.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, добрый вечер. Да, идею понял, спасибо. Буду тестировать различные варианты.