# TimeLineCollectionViewController.allProd.count всегда равен нулю. Из-за асинхронности, видимо. Как решить проблему с опозданием получения данных?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firestore

```
static func creatUserTimeLineProducts(completion: @escaping ([Product]) -> ()) {
        Firestore.firestore()
        //        получаем список Магазинов
            .collection("stores")
            .getDocuments { stores, error in
                print("Магазинов: \(stores!.count)")
                //                проходим по всем Магазинам
                for store in stores!.documents {
                    let storeRef = store.reference
                    //                    заходим в Продукты
                    storeRef.collection("products")
                        .getDocuments { products, error in
                            print("Продуктов: \(products!.count)")
                            //                            получаем все Продукты
                            let prods = products?.documents.compactMap({ Product(productDict: $0.data() )})
                            for prod in prods! {
                                FBDataBase.allProdArray.append(prod)
                            }
                            completion(FBDataBase.allProdArray)

                        }
                }
            }
    }


    func loadind() {
    FBDataBase.creatUserTimeLineProducts { all in
        TimeLineCollectionViewController.allProd = all
    }
    TimeLineCollectionViewController.allProd = FBDataBase.allProdArray
    print("Количество Айтемс Покупатели loading: \(TimeLineCollectionViewController.allProd.count)")

}

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
        switch AuthAccaunt.authProfile {
        case .store:
            FBDataBase.creatDB { prodArray in
                TimeLineCollectionViewController.prodArray = prodArray
            }
            
        case .user:
            loadind()
```

Comment: Нужно вызвать tableView.reloadData() после TimeLineCollectionViewController.allProd = all в фукнции loading

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, добрый день и под этим вопросом, Олег! Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Отпишусь по результату.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, попробовал, не получается. Все так же по-прежнему получаю ноль(

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, в обще решил проблему. Я наборот поднял completion на уровень выше - в последний for in. Думаю, это связано с тем, что функция сложная, состоит из вложений запросов в Firestore, которые сами по себе асинхронные.